# What happens if I use VCP on a FTDI (FT2232H) setted in UART mode? [COM not well talking]

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, uart, ftdi

I'm working on a `C#` program that is basically a `char` sequence's listener in a `SerialPort`which is connected to a FT2232H.
The sequence should start with an arbitrary `char` and has an arbitrary lenght.
The problem is not that I don't have the correct pattern I expected, the problem is that I don't have the chars I passed into the chip at all, and sometimes they're mixed with other bytes I'm sure to not have passed to the chip!

Even coding this char by char reader didn't help me to understand what happens inside.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FTDI_VCP
{
class SerialPortProgram
    {
    int _test_counter = 0;
    private string _buffer;
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM11",
      9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.Two);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new SerialPortProgram();
    }

    private SerialPortProgram()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("incoming chars:");

        port.DataReceived += new
          SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

        port.Open();

       Application.Run();
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
      SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {


        if(port.BytesToRead != 0)
        {
            do {
                int byte2read = port.ReadChar();
                if(byte2read == 0xFF) //this is my arbitrary char value
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write((char)port.ReadChar());
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtcgH.png)

**Suppositions:**

I think that using a VCP through a FTDI in UART-RS232 mode I am listening directly on the UART buffer however I fear that there are remote possibilities that I'm reading a something else instead of simple chars. Maybe RS232 packets? Maybe another pattern? I don't know. Can anyone help me to understand what happens inside a UART buffer when I'm using a COM port?

**Things I've already checked that seems to be okay**

1. Baud rate mismatching
2. Other devices interferring
3. FTDI in right mode, [I used FT_Prog like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wafq1.png)

***Thanks for the attention payed. I'm waiting for a FTDI GURU to help me (:***

Comment: Aside from the baud rate, have you checked that the parity, number of data bits, number of stopp bits and handshaking (RTS, Xon/Xoff) match?

Comment: Generally, the `StopBits` should be `One`.  As @ckuri suggested, check your parity, stop bits, and hardware handshaking.

Comment: Also, the `Parity` is generally set to `none`.  Just confirm with your hardware device that it should be set to what you have your serial port initializing to.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Baddack,the Parity and the StopBits settings changed the way to talk with the port! (:

Comment: Does that mean it is working now?

Comment: Yes, definitively! I'm a newbie in stackoverflow, so don't know how to set yours as the right answer :/